# Remove Default selection in Select2 Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using select2 for Multiselect option in my form.In the form I am using key controls to traverse thru the form.So If I press tab key it should traverse thru the fields in the forms.When I press tab to go to select2 textbox,it opens the options with default selection of first item.When I press tab to move to another field,it automatically selected.I want to avoid this.Please help...

I want to avoid default first element selection in select2 plugin.I have tried remove highlight() function when calling select2.It is working but not able to select element.

```js
    $("#" + elementID).select2({
        data: {results: itemArray, name: 'name'},
        formatSelection: format,
        formatResult: format,
        multiple: true,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        allowClear:true,
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [];
            $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
               data.push({id: this.toString(), name: this.toString()});
            });
           return callback(data);
        },
        createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
            
            if ($(data).filter(function () {
                return this.name.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
               return {id: term, name: term};
            }
    
        }

    }).select2('data', null).one('select2-focus', select2Focus).on("select2-blur", function () {
    $(this).one('select2-focus', select2Focus);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried allowClear option?

Comment: Yes but that also doesn't work

Comment: You can try adding empty value `{id:'', text:''}` which would be first item and would get selected

Comment: where I can add this line.Either to initselection..I will attach my code in the question itself.Pls refer it

Comment: you should append it to the data array which you pass when initialize select2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ykLnp54w/1/ I cannot see the problem you're facing, can you try to reproduce it in fiddle?

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21413241/104380

Answer (score 6):

You might need to add the `multiple` attribute to the select itself

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" multiple="multiple">
...
</select>
```

Ref: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3878

Comment: I've been searching for an answer for the last 2 hours and because this one had an downvote i didn't test it right away :sad  thanks @Tincho825

Answer (score 4):

Put this as a first option in your select, in HTML

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Select item...</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an empty option will fix the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').select2({
  placeholder: {
      id: '', // the value of the option
      text: 'None Selected'
    },
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width : 150px">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jesrsey</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `placeholder: {value: '',text: 'None Selected'},`

Comment: @YasserCHENIK It is placeholder: {id: '',text: 'None Selected'}

Comment: @KoikiDamilare in your comment, you said `// the value of the option`  but `id:` != `value:`

Comment: @YasserCHENIK I did not make the comment, I only replied you cos I tried the answer in the comment and it worked, I changed id to value like you stated but it did not work

Comment: @KoikiDamilare Alright. But that's a little bit weird.