# How do I hide the search box and placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need help with `select2`. Right now I have a search box with this JQuery code in the head. When I preview it there's no place holder either.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
  placeholder: "Select a Townhall Level",
    allowClear: true
  });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Here's an image:
[image]

So I wonder how do I hide the search too? I have no experience at all with JQuery so help would be appreciated.
Thank you for taking your time to read!

Here's my html: http://pastebin.com/P8in7ASX

Comment: Could you post the html part as well please

Comment: Are you using php?  And what determines if you want it displayed or hidden?

Comment: Here's my html: http://pastebin.com/P8in7ASX @GeorgeLee

Comment: @SariRahal Right now I'm only doing the designing part but I will use php later to code the functions :)

Comment: The placeholder doesn't show up because you don't have an empty option as the first option in your select (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25410119/4665459).  But why are you using select2 if you don't want the search box?

Comment: @MarkLeiber So how do I add the empty option?

Comment: Just add `<option></option>` as the first thing inside your `<select>`.

Comment: @MarkLeiberit worked! Thank you so much for fixing the placeholder! 
Do you know how to hide the search aswell? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the search by setting minimumResultsForSearch like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a Townhall Level",
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

And you can show the placeholder if you have an empty option as the first option in your select:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    ... other options ...
</select>
```

If you want to target specific selects rather than all of them, with the ability to apply different properties to each, change to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#targetElement1').select2({
    ... the properties you want applied to targetElement1 ...
  });

  $('#targetElement2').select2({
    ... the properties you want applied to targetElement2 ...
  });  
});
```

And give your selects IDs:

```
<select id="targetElement1">
    <option></option>
    ... other options ...
</select>

<select id="targetElement2">
    <option></option>
    ... other options ...
</select>
```

Comment: what if I want to use this for a particular box?

Comment: @JohnBorton, see my update for how to target a specific element.

Comment: thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it, Is there a way I can contact you like a pm here or so?
I can't thank you enough for this, thanks once again!

Comment: Edit: Target elemet didn't work for some reason even though I did exactly as  you stated :)

Comment: It works.  Make sure you copy it correctly, and make sure you don't still have the older code that uses $('select').

Comment: But I want to have the old one since I need it for the placeholder and the new one needs another placeholder so how should I do it then?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.