# select2 - how can I init and default to placeholder when no value is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to get `select2` to display placeholder when HTML `<select>` does not have an option selected.

My HTML select - no options have "selected" attribute and there's no "empty" option either:

```
<select id="el" style="width:300px">
    <option value="1">United States</option>
    <option value="2">Canada</option>
</select>
```

On page load I do this:

```
$('#el').val(null);
```

As a result, my combo looks like this - you can see that no option is selected:

[image]

Then, I init `select2`:

```
$('#el').select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: '(select...)'
});
```

and combo turns into `select2` control with "United States" being selected:

[image]

However, I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I.e. when my combo's value is NULL (or selectedIndex is -1), I would like `select2` to display the placeholder **(select...)** as opposed to the first `<option>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413241/how-to-use-placeholder-as-default-value-in-select2-framework. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25410119/5360631)

Comment: The "accepted" answer does not work in the suggested solution. Firstly, it does not render the placeholder, secondly it also renders empty element as first option. Not helpful.

Comment: It does work? https://jsfiddle.net/kqqeet2s/1/ from the documentation https://select2.github.io/options.html#my-first-option-is-being-displayed-instead-of-my-placeholder