# Placeholder not working in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am working `Select2`  Select-box.

#### Problem

Placeholder is not showing in `select2`. It is always show the first option selected in the `select2`. It's automatically select first option i want to show the placeholder instead of it.

[image]

#### My Code:

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var data = $('#test_skill').select2({
            placeholder: "Please select an skill",
            allowClear: true
       });
    });

// I have also tried this: This is also not working
    $('#test_skill').select2({
      placeholder: {
        id: '-1', // the value of the option
        text: 'Please select an skill'
      } 
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="skills_select2" required name="test_skill" id="test_skill">          
    <option value="1">TEST1</option>
    <option value="2">TEST2</option>
    <option value="3">TEST3</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: did you include select2 js and jquery

Comment: Yes, sir. I have included it properly. @Pritamkumar

Comment: Otherwise check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413241/how-to-use-placeholder-as-default-value-in-select2-framework

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just put `<option></option>` in select on first place:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $selectElement = $('#test_skill').select2({
    placeholder: "Please select an skill",
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

```css
.skills_select2 {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" />
<select class="skills_select2" required name="test_skill" id="test_skill">   
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">TEST1</option>
    <option value="2">TEST2</option>
    <option value="3">TEST3</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: Mantaps! Gracias! Thank you!

Comment: The empty <option></option> tag is required for this to work!

Answer (score 14):

For placeholders to work properly you have to add an empty option (i.e. ) as a first element to see a placeholder.

From Select2 documentation :

"Note that because browsers assume the first option element is selected in non-multi-value select boxes an empty first option element must be provided () for the placeholder to work."

for example:

```
<select class="skills_select2" required name="test_skill" id="test_skill"> 
    <option></option>    
    <option value="1">TEST1</option>
    <option value="2">TEST2</option>
    <option value="3">TEST3</option>            
</select>
```

and javascript would be:

```
$("#test_skill").attr(
   "data-placeholder","Please select an skill"
);
```

Comment: This one has the correct reason why we need the empy option.

Answer (score 6):

How about setting it in html

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled  selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="your value ">your value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: However your answer is a workaround sir. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Loved this approach! Simple, elegant. Resistant to api changes in select2 jq.

Answer (score 3):

Override `templateSelection` solve the problem:

```
templateSelection: function(item) { 
   return item.name  // "name" property of received data from ajax
               || item.text; // "text" value of default selected option or placeholder text
}
```

[Original answer](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4748)

Comment: The `|| item.text` fixed it for me, as I was using a the templateSelection option and I was only returning the `item.name` value

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution for this. Add the `data-placeholder` attribute and add a empty value option.

```
<select class="skills_select2" data-placeholder="Please select an option" required name="test_skill" id="test_skill"> 
    <option></option>    
    <option value="1">TEST1</option>
    <option value="2">TEST2</option>
    <option value="3">TEST3</option>            
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

the best way for me is to set it like below:
unshift the very first value to the data/result and set the placeholder in select2

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'api/v1/users',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
        let data = $.map(response, function(responseData) {
          return {
            id: responseData.id,
            text: responseData.name
          }
        });
        const selectedElement = $('#user_id');

        selectedElement.html('');

        data.unshift({id: -1, text: '', selected: 'selected', search:'', hidden:true });

        selectedElement.select2({
          theme: 'bootstrap',
          data: data,
          placeholder: {
            id: "-1",
            text: '--- Please select a user ---',
            selected:'selected'
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the change event of select

```
$('#targetSelect').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#targetSelect').trigger('change.select2'); // Limiting the scope of the change event
```

Reference : https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event

Comment: This worked in my case, where I couldn't add an empty <option>.