# PlaceHolder is not displaying in Select2 drop down on Modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `Select2` on a Modal. I am using `multiple="multiple"` attribute. My `Select2` is inside a BootStrap Modal. My HTML code is like below

```
<select class="form-control dropdown my_select" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="example1">Example1</option>
   <option value="example2">Example2</option>
</select>
```

My jQuery code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
  $('#modelId').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('.dropdown').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
     });
  });
});
```

But PlaceHolder is not displaying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder not working in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148297/placeholder-not-working-in-select2)

Comment: Thanks @Alex83690. I am using multiple="multiple" attribute

Comment: Yes but you don't have a blank (or disabled) first option like the replies in that link suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the placeholder , there must be some versioning issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {                
  
     $('.dropdown').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an option',
     
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="form-control dropdown my_select" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="example1">Example1</option>
   <option value="example2">Example2</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>
```

In your case just try to give diffrent color to placeholder

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: My select2 is inside a BootStrap Modal.

Comment: just try placeholder color , i have edited my answer